# Pass a vector of variables into lm() formula

Tags: r, paste, lm

I was trying to automate a piece of my code so that programming become less tedious.

Basically I was trying to do a stepwise selection of variables using `fastbw()` in the **rms** package. I would like to pass the list of variables selected by `fastbw()` into a formula as `y ~ x1+x2+x3`, "x1" "x2" "x3" being the list of variables selected by `fastbw()`

Here is the code I tried and did not work

```
olsOAW0.r060 <- ols(roll_pct~byoy+trans_YoY+change18m, 
                    subset= helper=="POPNOAW0_r060", 
                    na.action = na.exclude, 
                    data = modelready)

OAW0 <- fastbw(olsOAW0.r060, rule="p", type="residual", sls= 0.05)

vec <- as.vector(OAW0$names.kept, mode="any")

b <- paste(vec, sep ="+") ##I even tried b <- paste(OAW0$names.kept, sep="+")

bestp.OAW0.r060 <- lm(roll_pct ~ b , 
                      data = modelready, 
                      subset = helper =="POPNOAW0_r060",    
                      na.action = na.exclude)
```

I am new to R and still haven't trailed the steep learning curve, so apologize for obvious programming blunders.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You're almost there. You just have to `paste` the *entire* formula together, something like this:

```
paste("roll_pct ~ ",b,sep = "")
```

coerce it to an actual formula using `as.formula` and then pass *that* to `lm`. Technically, I think `lm` may coerce a character string itself, but coercing it yourself is generally safer. (Some functions that expect formulas won't do the coercion for you, others will.)

Comment: JJoran, thankyou, I still have error  .please take a look                             hpi <- paste   ("byoy", "change18m" , "change24m" , "change18m0", "change24m0", "lag3byoy" , "lag3change18m" , "lag3change24m", "lag6byoy", "lag6change18m", "lag6change24m", "trans_YoY" , sep ="+")
hpi.form <- as.formula(paste("roll_pct~", "hpi", sep = ""))
lmNGC0.r060 <- lm(hpi.form, subset= helper== "POPNOANGC0_r060",na.action = na.exclude, data = modelready)
> Error in model.frame.default(formula = as.formula(paste("roll_pct~", "hpi",:variable lengths differ (found for 'hpi')

Comment: @user1199861 You put `hpi` in quotes in the second line. Type `hpi.form` at the console and you'll see why this is wrong.

Comment: Joran, thanks once again, i think lm() is not coercing the object "hpi" into the formula as character string. When I tried typing the variables into the lm() formula, it worked

Comment: @user1199861 No, you pasted it together wrong. You wrote: `paste("roll_pct~", "hpi", sep = "")`, rather than `paste("roll_pct~", hpi, sep = "")` as I indicated in my answer.

Comment: Joran, thanks, you spotted it . Got it work this time..... thank you for being patient with me

Comment: doesn't work with formula in stats::aggregate function

Comment: @Peter.k Yes, `aggregate` is one of the cases where you'd need to coerce it yourself via `as.formula`.

Comment: I found you need to use `collapse` instead of `sep` in the first `paste` (for the vector) (as suggested in the somewhat overlooked answer by @cconnell)

Answer (score 31):

You would actually need to use collapse instead of seb when defining b.

```
b <- paste(OAW0$names.kept, collapse="+")
```

Then you can put it in joran answer

```
paste("roll_pct ~ ",b,sep = "")
```

or just use:

```
paste("roll_pct ~ ",paste(OAW0$names.kept, collapse="+"),sep = "")
```

Answer (score 13):

I ran into similar issue today, if you want to make it even more generic where you don't even have to have fixed class name, you can use

```
frmla <- as.formula(paste(colnames(modelready)[1], paste(colnames(modelready)[2:ncol(modelready)], sep = "", 
                              collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))
```

This assumes that you have class variable or the dependent variable in the first column but indexing can be easily switched to last column as:

```
frmla <- as.formula(paste(colnames(modelready)[ncol(modelready)], paste(colnames(modelready)[1:(ncol(modelready)-1)], sep = "", 
                              collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))
```

Then continue with `lm` using:

```
bestp.OAW0.r060 <- lm(frmla , data = modelready, ... )
```

Comment: This answer almost 3 years old but very simple and elegant - and saved me much time - upvote.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something less verbose:

```
fm <- as.formula( paste( colnames(df)[i], ".", sep=" ~ ")) 
                                      # i is the index of the outcome column
```

Here it is in a function:

```
getFormula<-function(target, df) {

  i <- grep(target,colnames(df))
  as.formula(paste(colnames(df)[i], 
                   ".", 
                   sep = " ~ "))
}
fm <- getFormula("myOutcomeColumnName", myDataFrame)
rp <- rpart(fm, data = myDataFrame) # Use the formula to build a model
```

Answer (score 2):

One trick that I use in similar situations is to subset your data and simply use e.g. `lm(dep_var ~ ., data = your_data)`.

Example

```
data(mtcars)
ind_vars <- c("mpg", "cyl")
dep_var <- "hp"

temp_subset <- dplyr::select(mtcars, dep_var, ind_vars)

lm(hp ~., data = temp_subset)
```

Answer (score 0):

just to simplify and collect above answers, based on a function

```
my_formula<- function(colPosition, trainSet){
    dep_part<- paste(colnames(trainSet)[colPosition],"~",sep=" ")
    ind_part<- paste(colnames(trainSet)[-colPosition],collapse=" + ")
    dt_formula<- as.formula(paste(dep_part,ind_part,sep=" "))
    return(dt_formula)
}
```

To use it:

```
my_formula( dependent_var_position, myTrainSet)
```