# How to use paste to get formula

Tags: r

In R, I have two strings and one vector containing several strings.

```
str1 <- "this_guy"
str2 <- "that_guy"
strvec <- c("str3", "str4", "str5")
```

How can I paste these together so that I get:

```
"str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 + str5"
```

A straightforward application of paste() such as

```
paste(str1, str2, strvec, sep = "+")
```

doesn't work

Comment: even better to use `reformulate`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951442/formula-with-dynamic-number-of-variables and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238038/passing-a-vector-of-variables-into-lm-formula .

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure which one you mean (names or vectors) so here are both. You can use `ls` to capture the pattern `str[0-9]+` from your global environment or `mget(ls(...))` to get the actual string., i.e.

```
paste(c(ls(pattern = 'str[0-9]+'), strvec), collapse = ' + ')
#[1] "str1 + str2 + str3 + str4 + str5"

paste(c(mget(ls(pattern = 'str[0-9]+')), strvec), collapse = ' + ')
#[1] "this_guy + that_guy + str3 + str4 + str5"
```